# Print script content (Python)

Tags: python, command-line

Using Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1,

I have a python script (stuff.py)

I want to open the command line and type a command that is going to print the content of that script, in text format.

What are my options?

Comment: are you talking about [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))?

Comment: Similar concept but no. I really just want to give the command line a command that will print out the source code of my stuff.py file.

Comment: ah. So `type stuff.py` it is, yep. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical *nix system, printing the contents of a file would be

```
cat stuff.py
```

*and for your edited critierion, Windows 8:*

```
type stuff.py
```

Or if your question is restricted to Python, then you can also write a script to do similar:

```
with open("stuff.py", "r") as f:
    print "\n".join(f.readlines())
```

Comment: Spot on `type stuff.py` Thx